# jQuery Autocomplete() not working in Struts

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to implement jQuery autocomplete feature. but it is not working. my code as follows.

```
$(".autoinputName").keyup(function(){
  var input=$("#autoinput").val();

// if(input.length >2){

     $.get("ajaxForm.do?input="+input,function(response){

         var data=response.numbers;

          data_array=data.split(",");

         $( "#autoinput" ).autocomplete({
            source: data_array 
        });
     });//end of get function
  //}
});

<input id="autoinput" class="autoinputName" />
```

i am getting values for  data_array,  data_array = one,two,three   from action class.
could you please suggest me how to solve.

Comment: its because everytime when keyup auto Complete is just initialize..you can specify server side url inside auto Complete too./

Answer (score 0):

use the [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)'s [source](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) property to make the ajax request

```
$(function(){


  $(".autoinputName").autocomplete({
      source : function(request, callback) {
          $.get("ajaxForm.do", {
              input : request.term,
              dataType: 'json'
          }, function(response) {
              var data = response.numbers;
              var data_array = data.split(",");
              callback(data_array)
          });
      }
  });

});
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qrdCLDrjhNfdb0BDBuJo?p=preview)